# FilterView, get_context_data() does not work. No attribute 'object_list' but there is one

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-filter

I am using django_tables2 with django_filter. When trying to edit context in `def post()`, so first getting actuall context (`context=get_context_data(self)`) it shows error:

```
'FilteredZamTableView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

But it does have object_list attribute! This is ridiculous. I printed it inside `get_context_data()` declaration

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print(context)
    return context
```

It shows:

```
{'paginator': <django.core.paginator.Paginator object at 0x0000024EBAABE7F0>, 'page_obj': <Page 1 of 2>, 'is_paginated': True, 'object_list': <QuerySet [---CONTENT---]>...
```

Here's my class based view with post method.

```
class FilteredZamTableView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = ZamTable
    template_name = 'home.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    filterset_class = ZamFilter

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get('accept'):
            try:
                context = get_context_data(self)  <---------------------------       ERROR
                return redirect('home')
            except Exception as e_msg:
                print(e_msg)
                return redirect('home')
```

It honestly looks like an error in django_filters.

Comment: try to use ListView instead of FilterView

Comment: And why exactly do you want to handle POST requests in a page listing / filtering objects? I would say the error is correct. Likely you see it having `object_list` in the case of a GET request. `FilterView` handles getting the object list in that case. While your post method is not handling that. Also why do you write `get_context_data(self)` instead of `self.get_context_data()`?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I render the table with one, additional column which contains a button. Button changes status of the object (a bit like a 0/1 switch). So there is one button in every row. I need to handle the change and "refresh" the table. I wanted to add toastr message box after succesful change or error message. That's why I need the context, add message to it and refresh the page displaying it.

Comment: Handle the post request in a different view and redirect back to this view. Use the [message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/) to store a message in that different view and display it here.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it makes much more sense to have it in different view, I moved everything that handles user input to it. Didn't think of message framework, I'm still learning. I think I will manage to use it. Thank you for helping, I couldn't figure out logical way of doing what I want.